# How to capture session name into tmux variable?

Tags: environment-variables, tmux

I want to execute an external command based on the value of my session name.  I know that the `:display-message '#S'` will give me the session name, but I want to have that name automatically sent to my external command.

I've tried `:run-shell "my-command #S"`, but it does not work, as "#S" is not substituted.

Is there anything like `:MY_VAR=$(display-message -p "#S")` that I could use?

Comment: Has there been any progress on this? tmux 1.9 still does not expand `#(/bin/echo "#S")`. Instead it passes "#S", not the acutal session name

Answer (score 2):

Since you can run almost all *tmux* commands directly from a shell (not just from a *tmux* `:` prompt), you can do this:

```
:run-shell "my-command \"$(tmux display -p '#S')\""
```

Of course this can also be done from a binding:

```
:bind C run-shell "my-command \"$(tmux display -p '#S')\""
```

Comment: But if I have two different sessions open, it will print the name of the session that's currently in focus, not necessarily the session that spawned `run-shell`...

Comment: Right, the environment created for the commands started by `run-shell` is the “global” environment, so “the current session” will always refer to the most recently active session (because the last component of the value of the TMUX environment variable is -1 instead of an (internal) session index). If you want to run a command inside the context of a session, then maybe you should use a (transient) detached window to run your command: `new-window -d 'my-command "$(tmux display -p "#S")"'` (or write `my-command` to do the `tmux display -p '#S'` part itself instead of its parent shell doing it).

Answer (score 1):

If you are running tmux 1.8 (you can check with `tmux -V`), you can simply use `:run-shell "my-command '#S'"`. This doesn't work in 1.6, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use sed + xargs to pass the result as a parameter to your desired command, eg:

```
tmux bind-key "C" run-shell "tmux display-message -p '#{S}' | sed 's/.*/\"&\"/' | xargs my_command"
```